# Can I avoid need access to Photos/Media/Files on play store

Tags: android, google-play, xamarin.forms

It is my first app on play store, when I am trying to install app from play store I get the following Message:

> need access to "Photos/Media/Files"

how I can avoid this message to appear when some one trying to install my app, I think it is not friendly for all users: 
I am using **Xamarin.Forms** 
on the following my android.manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.mnakabalshabaviewbook" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
    <application android:label="xxx "></application>
</manifest>
```

[image]

Comment: Remove the permissions you have added, from your manifest file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this part](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/permissions/) of the Xamarin documentation.

Just take out the permissions that you don't need.
When you submit your app to the developer console you can check which permissions are requested.  You can do this when you upload a new APK file, or check it afterwards.

For this go to your dashboard and click your app in the overview. In this app find the APK tab.

[image: APK tab]

In this tab you can find all versions you have ever uploaded.
Click on a version in the list and in the popup that comes up which permissions are requested for that APK.

[image: APK permissions]

Comment: how i can check which permissions are requested on developer console because on manifest no one selected

Comment: i recommend you to resize pik using paint ...i think it is useful answer let me check it .. thanks

Comment: You are right! Resized it a bit. It it _is_ helpful please accept it as an answer.

Comment: ..actually i am using plugin.media ..is a way to avoid this message ..it is appear unfriendly for customer

Comment: There is no way around this message. If you are using the camera the user wants to know and deserves to know! This is a safety measure built-in to Android. This way the user is informed if some weird permissions are requested. So the user should actually be happy that this message comes up!